# Login fails with C# application / SQL Server database installed in a different machine

Tags: c#, sql-server, authentication, credentials, desktop

I created a desktop application which runs with SQL Database. In my machine installation runs perfect. When installing in other machines it do not. Message is:

> Cannot open database “verticaladminmod” requested by the login. The login failed. Login failed for “Fina-PC\Fina”

My machine:

- Name “MI_PC-PC”
- Owner: “MI_PC-PC\MI_PC”
- Database: “verticaladminmod”

Connection string:

```
Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=verticaladminmod;Integrated Security=True
```

- Windows 7 64 bit
- SQL Server 2014 Express, instance “SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER)”

Other machine installation:

- Name “FINA-PC”
- User Name: “Fina-PC\Fina”
- Windows 7 32 bit
- SQL Server 2012 Express, instance “SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER)”

Already understand it should be a matter of credentials, but after several attempts could not get to make it work. Need specific orientation with detailed steps if possible in order to configure where needed looking forward to resolve this issue and understand it in depth as well. Thank you so much!

Comment: You know Windows 7 has been unsupported (end of life) for nearly a year now? As in, no new updates... not even critical security patches? It's dangerous and irresponsible to still be using it.

Answer (score 1):

First, the connection string needs to point at the correct machine (`FINA-PC` rather than `localhost`). In some cases you need an instance there, as well (ie `FINA-PC\MSSQLSERVER`), but with the default instance you can skip the instance name. This is why `localhost` worked in the original connection string.

Once that is fixed, we can talk about authentication. If you want integrated security to work across machines you also want to have an Active Directory domain. If you don't have an Active Directory domain, you want to switch to SQL authentication.

SQL authentication requires you to create a user ("login", in Sql Server parlance) in the database with it's own username and password you can put in the connection string. *Do not use the sa account for this.* You must also then be very careful with how you store the connection string, or any decompiler will show the credential and provide full access to your DB. Once you have the new login and connection string, you must also grant permissions for the account to do the operations you need within your database.

Comment: Thank you Joel, tried with FINA-PC rather than localhost and later tried with FINA-PC\MSSQLSERVER. Both cases had error : 25 String chain not valid. Other, please explain what is a "Active Directory Domain". Thank you so much

Comment: @OscarRossi If you need to ask, you don't have one and can't get one. Skip to paragraph three.

Comment: Also, as it's an SQL Express, make sure TCP/IP comunication is activated.